# Error: "." no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: npm

Cuándo ejecuto el comando **npm run local** me aparece esto en la consola: *"." no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.*
No entiendo porque me indica el punto.

Comment: Debes de adjuntar mas información acerca del error, como capturas o en que tipo de consola estas llevando acabo la acción, por lo que entiendo estas intentando correr o ejecutar ese comando en consola CMD y ese error hace referencia a que literalmente no reconoce el comando. Si acabas de instalar las librerías o programas para Node JS o React debes checar si realizaste la configuración correctamente, por lo regular el error se soluciona agregando la ruta de instalación /bin a tu PATH en variables de entorno, pero revisa la documentación.